# Linq on related table - query

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Simplified. EF6

I have two tables related on the PersonId

```
 Person
    PersonPK

 FavouriteFood
    PersonFK
    FoodName
```

I want to get all the Persons which have a favourite food of "Tomatoes"

```
_db.Persons(p=>p.FavouriteFoods(???????))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like there is a One to Many relations ship between a `Person` and `FavouriteFoods`, you can get the result like:

```
var query = _db.Person
               .Where(r=> 
                      r.FavouriteFoods.Any(t => t.FoodName == "Tomatoes"));
```

If there is no relation between `Person` and `FavouriteFoods`, then you can get Distinct `PersonFK` from the `FavouriteFood` and then get records from `Person` table.

Something like:

```
var query = _db.Person
               .Where(r=> _db.FavouriteFoods
                          .Where(r=> r.FoodName == "Tomatoes")
                          .Select(t=> t.PersonFK)
                          .Distinct()
                          .Contains(r.PersonPK));
```